# php how can i rename file before upload via curl

Tags: php

i need to rename the image file before upload how can i do that i can use the rename but it moves the file to a different dir file_get_contents to change the name is not working for me  i need to rename this part `/C-laragon-www-api-backend-screenshots-1-jpg.jpg` this is the path on my system

here is my function

```
/**
 * @param $image
 * @return mixed|exception
 */
    function imgUpload($image)
    {
        try {
            $API_KEY = 'xxxxx';
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=' . $API_KEY);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            $extension = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $file_name = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
            $data = [
                'image' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($image, $file_name))
            ];
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
    
            curl_close($ch);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
        return json_decode($result, true);
        
    }
```

the output

```
 ["data"]=>
  array(12) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "xxxxx"
    ["title"]=>
    string(49) "C-laragon-www-api-backend-screenshots-1-jpg"
    ["url_viewer"]=>
    string(22) "https://ibb.co/xxxx"
    ["url"]=>
    string(78) "https://i.ibb.co/xxxx/C-laragon-www-api-backend-screenshots-1-jpg.jpg"
    ["display_url"]=>
    string(78) "https://i.ibb.co/xxxx/C-laragon-www-api-backend-screenshots-1-jpg.jpg"
    ["size"]=>
    int(435765)
    ["time"]=>
    string(10) "xxxxxx"
    ["expiration"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["image"]=>
    array(5) {
```

Comment: Post relevant parts of the code that you've tried, show the errors you got, and the effort you made. SO is NOT a: write code service.

Comment: updated the question:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
    function imgUpload($image)
    {
        try {
            $file = new \CURLFile("@{$image}"); //<-- Path of the image with @ in front
            $data = array('name' => 'New name of image', 'file' => $file);

            $API_KEY = 'xxxxx';
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=' . $API_KEY);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            $extension = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            // $file_name = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
    
            curl_close($ch);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
        return json_decode($result, true);
        
    }
```